# En un notebook de jupyter, ¿se puede ejecutar una función de otro notebook, para importar su retorno?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Mis notebooks se han hecho muy grandes y estoy pensando en alguna manera de dividirlos en otros más pequeños, si es que encuentro la manera de importarlos dentro del notebook principal como módulos, o bien importar el retorno de alguna de sus funciones. Estoy buscando en Internet y no acabo de encontrar un ejemplo. Quizás me podáis facilitarme algún enlace que explique esta opción. Agradeceré ayuda.

Además del enlace proporcionado por abulafia, he encontrado estos otros dos que me parecen muy útiles para estudiar este tema.

How to import ipynb file in jupyter notebook [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/58086016.html)

import-ipynb 0.1.3 : [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://pypi.org/project/import-ipynb/)

Comment: Realmente lo más simple es que salves el notebook como archivo python (o lo conviertas a un simple .py usando `nbconvert`). Haciendo eso el .py resultante tendrá el código de las celdas, pero no los resultados de ejecutarlas (aunque puede que éstos aparezcan insertados como comentarios). Una vez lo tienes como `.py` lo importarías normalmente (si está en la misma carpeta y si no configurando adecuadamente el PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Otra opción puede ser hacer lo que se explica [aqui](https://mindey.com/blog/importing-ipython-notebooks-as-modules), pero nunca lo he probado. Parece "magia avanzada".